# Unable to resolve module in React Native - however I want to make the module optional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a library where I want to make other dependencies optional. I am trying to import them into my application as such:

```
try {
  let GoogleSignin = require("@react-native-community/google-signin");
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Google Signin is not found");
}
try {
  let FBSDK = require("react-native-fbsdk");
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Facebook SDK is not found");
}
try {
  let InAppBrowser = require("react-native-inappbrowser-reborn");
} catch (e) {
  console.error("InApp Browser is not found");
}
try {
  let AppleAuth = require("@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication");
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Apple auth is not found");
}
```

However when I try to do this, I get the following error:

[image: Error screen]

Is there not a way to essentially ignore a missing library in React Native?

Comment: I would question why you would want to optionally require a package - use of type of auth should be defined in business logic outside of you imports. Please give more context

Comment: @Mr.Robot I am writing a library that will allow users to authenticate via Keycloak and token exchanges. Users will be able to call the particular type of auth that they want (I am essentially just writing a wrapper function that calls the auth library and processes the token exchange with keycloak)

Comment: @Mr.Robot It automates a fairly hard/annoying part of auth and Keycloak as it has to be done with various SDK libraries

Comment: @Keith Yes, that appears to work!