# Unknown named module in React Native when trying to make module optional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here's my previous question on this:

[Unable to resolve module in React Native - however I want to make the module optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704999/unable-to-resolve-module-in-react-native-however-i-want-to-make-the-module-opt)

And here is the resource I was pointed to:

[How to require module only if exist. React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722700/how-to-require-module-only-if-exist-react-native)

This is my current code:

```
let GoogleSignin;
const GoogleSigninInit = '@react-native-community/google-signin';
try {
  GoogleSignin = require.call(null, GoogleSigninTest);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Google Signin is not found");
}

let FBSDK;
const FBSDKInit = 'react-native-fbsdk';
try {
  FBSDK = require.call(null, FBSDKInit);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Facebook SDK is not found");
}

let InAppBrowser;
const InAppBrowserInit = 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn';
try {
  InAppBrowser = require.call(null, InAppBrowserInit);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log("InApp Browser is not found");
}

let AppleAuth;
const AppleAuthInit = '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';
try {
  AppleAuth = require.call(null, AppleAuthInit);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Apple auth is not found");
}
```

However, when I try to use `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn`, which is absolutely in my node_modules folder, I get the following error:

```
Unknown named module: "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn"
```

So the code I have has definitely gotten rid of the error from optional modules, however it doesn't seem to actually load them.

Is there a way to actually load the modules that I have in node_modules?

EDIT:

Here is the full stack trace for this particular module, but again, it happens with other modules too.

```
Unknown named module: "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn"
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:95:12 in metroRequire
- node_modules/react-native-keycloak-social-login/src/Login.js:25:25 in <global>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:321:4 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:20 in guardedLoadModule
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:128:6 in metroRequire
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:657:4 in runUpdatedModule
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:532:23 in metroHotUpdateModule
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:53:15 in define
* http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/react-native-keycloak-social-login/src/Login.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:1:1 in eval
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/injectUpdate.js:65:4 in inject
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [README](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser#using-react-native--060), the installation is not completely automatic and you need to follow further process depending on the platform and react-native version.

If you have followed the above, then try deleting your node_modules, running `npm cache clean` and reinstalling node_modules and running the app again.

Comment: It happens with every other module too, including ones that need no extra installation steps

Comment: For example, I tried it with this module, and had the same issue: https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper

Comment: Did you try re installing node_modules after cleaning your npm cache and then running the app again?

Comment: Just did, same problem.

Again, this is from the README for one particular module. I tried multiple modules and had the same error. It is not due to an issue with just this one particular module.

Comment: Where and how are you using these modules after importing? And what line on the code gives you the error?

Comment: I am using these modules optionally depending on whether or not they're installed to connect with a third party identity provider. The line that gives the error is InAppBrowser = require.call(null, InAppBrowserInit); - I put the full stack trace above